# How can you find the more recent build ID for a steam game?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am looking for a way to get automatically updated via node js when a steam game has a new update. I know that steam games increment their build ID each time there is an update so a way to find the build ID via an API would do the trick.

You can find the build ID manually from the game properties in steam and you can also find it by launching steam in console mode and the command app info. Therefore a way to communicate with steam in CLI form would probably also work.

Any way to do the afformentioned methods or a different method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it!

[This API](https://www.steamcmd.net/) lets you query any appID and from there you can find builds just look for the branches object